# How can I validate a number is between 0 - 999 using HTML5 client validation?

Tags: html

I can only find validation checks like this?

```
        <input required pattern="^d{3}-d{2}-d{4}$"
            title="###-##-####" />
```

Is there a way I can validate an input to ensure it's a number from 0 - 999 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input required pattern="^\d{1,3}$" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

```
<input required pattern="\d{1,3}">

<input required type=number min=0 max=999>
```

These create different user interfaces. On non-supporting browsers, they both fall back to a normal input field with no checks.